# How to change getElementbyID script to getElementsbyclassname?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a script for a pop up booking tool I am trying to implement onto my site.

The script provided by the company is tied to a getElementbyID, but I need to be able to use the scirpt for several locations on a page, so I need to convert it.

Here is the script I am working with:

```
<script>

document.getElementById('teachworks-booking-button').onclick = function() 
{
    document.getElementById('teachworks-booking-button').insertAdjacentHTML("afterend","<iframe id='booking-iframe' src='redacted" + window.location.origin + "&type=iframe' style='width:100%;height:100%;position:fixed;top:0;left:0;z-index:1000000;'></iframe>");
}
// event listener
var eventMethod = window.addEventListener ? "addEventListener" : "attachEvent";
var eventer = window[eventMethod];
var messageEvent = eventMethod == "attachEvent" ? "onmessage" : "message";
eventer(messageEvent,function(e) {
  if(e.data == 'close'){
    document.getElementById('booking-iframe').remove();
  }
},false);

</script>
```

Can anyone help me create a script that allows for getElementsbyclassname or similar so I can use it easily across my site?

Thanks so much

Comment: For this element `document.getElementById('booking-iframe')` ?

Comment: @s.kuznetsov No, sorry for document.getElementById('teachworks-booking-button').onclick = function()

Comment: I made some code. Check it code. Does it work for you?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getElementsByClassName` implies accessing a *collection*, which means that you need to use a loop. I gave an example with method `forEach()`.

```
Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("teachworks-booking-button")).forEach(function (btn_current) {
    btn_current.onclick = function () {
        this.insertAdjacentHTML("afterend", "<iframe id='booking-iframe' src='redacted" + window.location.origin + "&type=iframe' style='width:100%;height:100%;position:fixed;top:0;left:0;z-index:1000000;'></iframe>");
    };

    // event listener
    var eventMethod = window.addEventListener ? "addEventListener" : "attachEvent";
    var eventer = window[eventMethod];
    var messageEvent = eventMethod == "attachEvent" ? "onmessage" : "message";
    eventer(
        messageEvent,
        function (e) {
            if (e.data == "close") {
                document.getElementById("booking-iframe").remove();
            }
        },
        false
    );
});
```

Comment: This is almost there, but something is forcing the iframe open without needing to click the "teachworks-booking-button" and doesnt let you close the window.

Comment: @ZackCooper-Black, How can I see the complete code?

Comment: Well I've basically taken what you wrote, added it to my site above the </body> tag, and made all the buttons I need the script to execute on "teachworks-booking-button"

Comment: I'm thinking it has something to do with the loop, as changing the class name in the script does not stop it from opening the iframe window.

Comment: Nevermind, this totally works and I just forgot to add the <script> tags. Thanks so much @s.kuznetsov!

Comment: @ZackCooper-Black, I apologize for the long answer. The road to the house was long :) I was glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a good way to do

```js
  const id =
    document.getElementById('teachworks-booking-button').getAttribute("id");
    class =  document.getElementById('teachworks-booking-button').class=id;
    //if the id already have class then use this
    document.getElementById('teachworks-booking-button').classList.add(id);
```